# Norm to Principal Ideal

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory

Over a number field, given the norm of an principal ideal, is there a way to find the principal ideal?

Also, Given ideals is there an algorithm to find principal ideals?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sort' principal ideals? Do you mean to sort them by norm?

Comment: no, just to separate principal ideals. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There may be several principal ideals with the same norm.

Comment: no problem, but is there a way to find all possible principal ideals having the given norm?

Comment: To determine if an ideal is principal you may use algorithm 6.5.10 in Cohen's "A course on computational albegraic number theory". To find all ideals of a given norm it is good to know how to factor prime numbers; that is section 4.8 in the same book.

Comment: If the norm of the ideal is a prime number or a "relatively small" natural number, you can appeal to the well-known result that if $\mathfrak{a} = \langle   \alpha \rangle \neq  \langle 0  \rangle$ then $N(\mathfrak{a})$ is equal to the modulus of the norm of the element $\alpha$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Do you have some clues on the complexity of factoring $p = \pi \overline{\pi}$, say if we know $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ exists ? (my interrogation holds even for $\alpha= \sqrt{d}$)